# FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl needs a username

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Why do I need to pass a username to this method?  I just want the url that was redirected from for forms authentication...

FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the .NET framework needs to know which user was redirected. Remember server side there are multiple users accessing the same application.

If you really want to know, use reflector to check out System.Web.Security.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it needs it either.  If you look at [the source code](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Security/FormsAuthentication@cs/1305376/FormsAuthentication@cs), it simply does a null check.  If the value of `userName` is null, it skips out and returns null.  If there is any non-null value, it proceeds, but still completely ignores the value.  It has nothing to do with the processing at all.

Also note that `createPersistentCookie` is ignored, both per the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) as well as is evident in the code.